# Failure to maintain the proper place ( HTML / CSS )

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

Please i have make something but when I add more one line i get the error [image: Example]

Style code

```
    #wrapper {
        max-width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 5%;
    }

    #posts {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #posts li {
        float: left;
          width: 28%;
          margin: 2.5%;
          background-color: #2183B9;
    }
    #posts li img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #posts li a{

        text-decoration: none;

    }
    #posts li a p{
        font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;  
        color: #ccc;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5%;
        font-size: 0.75em;

    }
```

When i delete some words it's back to his place .... Please who can help me to fix the error and thank you all so much

Comment: you need to provide html or something that reproduces the behaviour you are describing

Comment: That’s how float works. If you want them all aligned by their top edge, then don’t use float, but `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: @CBroe , it's work thank you so much and thx to all the guys comment to help me , I love you guys as friends :D

Comment: Added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That’s how float works.

If you want them all aligned by their top edge, then don’t use float, but `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some of the excess text being hidden you could use a fixed height and set overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the text you are including is increasing the size of the anchor tag used for the text pushing the other post down below. Make the **position** of the **anchor tag** that you are using for displaying the text **absolute** and fix it to the ***bottom of every post*** relative to the post `bottom:0px;` and set a **box-sizing** property on the post box so that the anchor tag if grows in size grows above and not below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's complete working code for a similar example. Hope this simplifies your problem :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .post{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 2em;
        position: relative;
    }
    .caption{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 2em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="post">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="300.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <p>This is the caption for the image and this one is quite long for it.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="300.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>This is the caption for the image and this one is very very very very very long and should be taken care of.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="300.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>This is the caption for the image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="300.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>This is the caption for the image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="300.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>This is the caption for the image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="300.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>This is the caption for the image</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind the images used should be optimised and should be of same sizes otherwise the code will break.

Comment: You should probably edit your original answer to include this. Do you really need two seperate answers to 1 quesion?